# Where to place child elements when using xsl:attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm quite new to XSLT. I have the following code which I'm sure could be made more clean / DRY:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="custom-link">
        <!-- Custom link -->
        <a class="no-ajax" href="{custom-link/item/@handle}">
            <img src="//images.mysite.com/2/1120/630/5{lead-image/@path}/{lead-image/filename}" alt="" />
        </a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Organic link -->
        <a class="no-ajax" href="/film/{primary-category/item/@handle}/{film-title/@handle}/">
            <img src="//images.mysite.com/2/1120/630/5{lead-image/@path}/{lead-image/filename}" alt="" />
        </a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Ideally I only want the `href` in the anchor to change. I've read you can do something like:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="custom-link">
                <!-- Custom link -->
                <xsl:value-of select="custom-link"/></xsl:text> 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Organic link -->
                <xsl:value-of select="organic-link"/></xsl:text> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

But I don't quite understand how to put the link values in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to evaluate code out of context. I believe the following:

```
<a class="no-ajax">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="custom-link">
                <xsl:value-of select="custom-link/item/@handle"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/film/', primary-category/item/@handle, '/', film-title/@handle, '/')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <img src="//images.mysite.com/2/1120/630/5{lead-image/@path}/{lead-image/filename}" alt="" />
</a>
```

is the streamlined equivalent of what you have now - so if that's working, so should this. But I have no way of testing it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use `xsl-attribute`

```
<a class="no-ajax>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="custom-link">
                <xsl:value-of select="custom-link/item/@handle"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/film/', primary-category/item/@handle, '/', film-title/@handle, '/')"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <img src="//images.mysite.com/2/1120/630/5{lead-image/@path}/{lead-image/filename}" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: That's not going to work: you cannot use *attribute value template* with the `select` attribute of `<xsl:value-of>`.

Comment: You are still copying his path, you have just taken out the `{}` as if they don't mean anything. They do.

Comment: Your code looks for a value of a (single) node in the source XML document. The path to that node starts at the root element `/film`. Whatever would be found at that node (if it existed*) would be the content of the `href` attribute. My code looks for the contents of **two** nodes and combines then with **literal text** - so in the end, the content of the `href` attribute (i.e. the actual link in the resulting HTML document ) will be a URL that starts with the '/film' directory. So that's two very different results. -- (*) I can tell you for certain that the node doesn't exist, because ...

Comment: ... because an attribute cannot have a child element.